# How can I in a simple way be able to use non CommonJS and es6 imports with webpack?

Tags: webpack

I want to use a library like nprogress: https://github.com/rstacruz/nprogress

But I have problems when I try to use it in my Angular 2 TypeScript project.

If I do:

```
require('nprogress/nprogress');
```

or

```
import 'nprogress/nprogress';
```

And try to use NProgress in my code then I get error message `EXCEPTION: NProgress is not defined`.

If I build the project I see that the file nprogress.js is being bundled before the Angular code, but it still does not work and NProgress is still not in global scope and cannot be found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Import css and js in the below way.

```js
import "nprogress/nprogress.css";
import * as nprogress from "nprogress";
```

To control the progress bar, call `nprogress.start();` and `nprogress.done();`

Comment: It does not work if I use it inside the constructor of app.component.ts, but if I execute right after the import statement then it works.

Comment: How can I make it globally available in every file?

Comment: It works I just need to import it in that file, thanks!

Comment: Use expose-loader to make modules global. https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader